# Android-How to move to 2 different activities from one activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A which has button, if you don't click on that button then it has to open another activity B after certain amount of time and if you click on the button it has to open activity C but should not open activity B.
I used handlers to do this but when i click on on a button it opens activity C but it opens activity B too after the time limit.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, FinalPage.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can pass flag with intent or check condtition

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a flag. You can write your code as

```
boolean flag=true;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, FinalPage.class);
                        if(flag){                        
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();}
                    }
                }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
            }
        });

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, Page.class);
                 flag=false;                        
                 startActivity(mainIntent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your handler code of opening the ActivityB will run anyway even if you move to different activity. You should make a variable to check if other activity is open or not. Or you can use in `onPause()` of ActivityA:

```
handler_ins.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
```

This will cancel currently pending tasks of handler right before switching to other activity.

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that Button is clicked then open activity C otherwise activity B and after click Boolean variable false or true

```
If(Button1.isClicked())
{
           Intent to activity C
}
else
{
           Intent to activity B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean value when the button is clicked, 'loadActivityC = false'. Declare it as true initially. Then if(loadActivityC), start the activity with the intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, FinalPage.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

And use it on button click before open new Activity

```
myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel the handler when user clicks on the activity C button.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the handler object and after the button click cancel the handler Thread,

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

Runnable myRunnableObj = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, FinalPage.class);
             startActivity(mainIntent);
             finish();
        }
    };
myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnableObj, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

And when click your button, cancel the handler callback,

```
myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnableObj);
```

Comment: Hi I used your code but its giving me error when I use myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnableObj); inside the onclick(button)

Comment: Ok, where the problem?

Comment: removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) used this instead of removeCallbacks(myRunnableObj)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean opennigFirstActivity = false;
boolean opennigSecondActivity = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, FinalPage.class);
            if (!opennigSecondActivity) {
                Log.d("First Activity", "Opening Second");
                opennigFirstActivity = true;
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Driving.this, Page.class);
            if (!opennigFirstActivity) {
                Log.d("First Activity", "Opening Third");
                opennigSecondActivity = true;
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Hopes it will help you.

Comment: I tried to add as you said but it still doing the same

Comment: I run the above code and it works absolutely fine for me. :)

Comment: I tried to vote but as i m new to stack overflow I need at least  15 reputations

Comment: No problem. Thanks :)